Do the equations $T_{\nu}(t)=\frac{T_{\nu ,0}}{a(t)}$ and $T_{\gamma}(t)=\frac{T_{\gamma,0}}{a(t)}$ actually hold at all times?
I’ve always been under the impression that $T_{\nu}(t)=\frac{T_{\nu ,0}}{a(t)}$ and $T_{\gamma}(t)=\frac{T_{\gamma,0}}{a(t)}$ describe the neutrino and photon temperatures (respectively) throughout the history of the universe. However, I’ve also always thought this was too good to be true especially due to the fact that interaction rates change with time. I can imagine why after decoupling this could be true, but beforehand I cannot.
I recently found this graph:
which seems inconsistent with $T_{\nu}(t)=\frac{T_{\nu ,0}}{a(t)}$ and $T_{\gamma}(t)=\frac{T_{\gamma,0}}{a(t)}$. From what I understand, the little bump in $T_{\gamma}$ is due to energy deposited from electron positron annihilation, which seems consistent with the doubts I mentioned above. I am wondering if 1) my conclusion is correct (these equations are not always correct) and 2) if so, how one would go about calculating $T_{\nu}$ and $T_{\gamma}$ in general (for instance, how would we calculate $T_{\gamma}$ after electron positron annihilation? How about $T{\nu}$ before decoupling?). If I had data that showed stuff that energy density and $H$ as a function of time(and/or $z$), is there a simple way to do this?
Sorry if this is somewhat of a basic question. I’d appreciate any help.
